# Make boost::progress_display work when more information is being printed to the screen

Tags: c++, boost, progress-bar

I have a console program which can take some time for its calculations. I am using `boost::progress_display` to provide some feedback to the user.

My problem is that I also want to print other updates to the standard output if certain things happen, and that breaks progress bar:

```
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
**Found temporary candidate with score: 40
Found temporary candidate with score: 46
*Found temporary candidate with score: 52
********Found temporary candidate with score: 55
**Found temporary candidate with score: 67
**************************************
```

Is there an easy way to have both a progress bar (ideally as non-intrusive in the code as `boost::progress_display`) and updates to the screen?

**EDIT:** after a suggestion in comments saying that I have not provided an example of what I am looking for, I want code which looks similar to this:

```
boost::progress_display progress(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i< 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Number is: " << i << "\n";
    ++progress;
}
```

but that doesn't result in this output:

```
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
Number is: 0
*****Number is: 1
*****Number is: 2
*****Number is: 3
*****Number is: 4
*****Number is: 5
*****Number is: 6
*****Number is: 7
*****Number is: 8
*****Number is: 9
******
```

Instead, I'd like the lines sayin `Number is: z`  to show up after the progress bar or before it:

```
Number is: 0
Number is: 1
Number is: 2
Number is: 3
Number is: 4
Number is: 5
Number is: 6
Number is: 7
Number is: 8
Number is: 9
0%   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100%
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
***************************************************
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use a homemade class

I could not find an easy answer using `boost::progress_display` so I implemented my own RAII class which is working like a charm under Linux:

**ProgressBar.h**

```
#ifndef PROGRESS_BAR_H
#define PROGRESS_BAR_H

#include <string>

/**
 * RAII implementation of a progress bar.
 */
class ProgressBar
{
public:
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * It takes two values: the expected number of iterations whose progress we
     * want to monitor and an initial message to be displayed on top of the bar
     * (which can be updated with updateLastPrintedMessage()).
     */
    ProgressBar(
            uint32_t expectedIterations, const std::string& initialMessage="");

    /**
     * Destructor to guarantee RAII.
     */
    ~ProgressBar();

    // Make the object non-copyable
    ProgressBar(const ProgressBar& o) = delete;
    ProgressBar& operator=(const ProgressBar& o) = delete;

    /**
     * Must be invoked when the progress bar is no longer needed to restore the
     * position of the cursor to the end of the output.
     * It is automatically invoked when the object is destroyed.
     */
    void endProgressBar();

    /**
     * Prints a new message under the last printed message, without overwriting
     * it. This moves the progress bar down to be placed under the newly
     * written message.
     */
    void printNewMessage(const std::string& message);

    /**
     * Prints a message while the progress bar is on the screen on top on the
     * last printed message. Since the cursor is right at the beginning of the
     * progress bar, it moves the cursor up by one line before printing, and
     * then returns it to its original position.
     */
    void updateLastPrintedMessage(const std::string& message);

    /**
     * Overloaded prefix operator, used to indicate that the has been a new
     * iteration.
     */
    void operator++();

private:
    unsigned int mTotalIterations;
    unsigned int mNumberOfTicks;
    bool mEnded;
    size_t mLengthOfLastPrintedMessage;
};

#endif /* PROGRESS_BAR_H */
```

**ProgressBar.cpp**

```
#include "ProgressBar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#define LENGTH_OF_PROGRESS_BAR 55
#define PERCENTAGE_BIN_SIZE (100.0/LENGTH_OF_PROGRESS_BAR)

namespace
{
    std::string generateProgressBar(unsigned int percentage)
    {
        const int progress = static_cast<int>(percentage/PERCENTAGE_BIN_SIZE);
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << " " << std::setw(3) << std::right << percentage << "% ";
        std::string bar("[" + std::string(LENGTH_OF_PROGRESS_BAR-2, ' ') + "]");

        unsigned int numberOfSymbols = std::min(
                std::max(0, progress - 1),
                LENGTH_OF_PROGRESS_BAR - 2);

        bar.replace(1, numberOfSymbols, std::string(numberOfSymbols, '|'));

        ss << bar;
        return ss.str();
    }
}

ProgressBar::ProgressBar(
            uint32_t expectedIterations, const std::string& initialMessage)
    : mTotalIterations(expectedIterations),
      mNumberOfTicks(0),
      mEnded(false)
{
    std::cout << initialMessage << "\n";
    mLengthOfLastPrintedMessage = initialMessage.size();
    std::cout << generateProgressBar(0) << "\r" << std::flush;
}

ProgressBar::~ProgressBar()
{
    endProgressBar();
}

void ProgressBar::operator++()
{
    if (mEnded)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                "Attempted to use progress bar after having terminated it");
    }

    mNumberOfTicks = std::min(mTotalIterations, mNumberOfTicks+1);
    const unsigned int percentage = static_cast<unsigned int>(
            mNumberOfTicks*100.0/mTotalIterations);

    std::cout << generateProgressBar(percentage) << "\r" << std::flush;
}

void ProgressBar::printNewMessage(const std::string& message)
{
    if (mEnded)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                "Attempted to use progress bar after having terminated it");
    }

    std::cout << "\r"
        << std::left
        << std::setw(LENGTH_OF_PROGRESS_BAR + 6)
        << message << "\n";
    mLengthOfLastPrintedMessage = message.size();
    const unsigned int percentage = static_cast<unsigned int>(
            mNumberOfTicks*100.0/mTotalIterations);

    std::cout << generateProgressBar(percentage) << "\r" << std::flush;

}

void ProgressBar::updateLastPrintedMessage(const std::string& message)
{
    if (mEnded)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                "Attempted to use progress bar after having terminated it");
    }

    std::cout << "\r\033[F"
        << std::left
        << std::setw(mLengthOfLastPrintedMessage)
        << message << "\n";
    mLengthOfLastPrintedMessage = message.size();
}

void ProgressBar::endProgressBar()
{
    if (!mEnded)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(2, '\n');
    }
    mEnded = true;
}
```

## How to use it

These are two pieces of code showing how it can be used and the output one can expect:

**updating.cpp**

```
#include "ProgressBar.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#define ITERATIONS 10

int main()
{
    ProgressBar progress(ITERATIONS, "No odd number found");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        // Sleep for 0.5s so that the gif is clear enough
        usleep(500000);

        if (i%2 != 0)
        {
            progress.updateLastPrintedMessage(
                    "New odd number found: " + std::to_string(i));
        }

        ++progress;
    }
}
```

**Output of updating.cpp**

[image]

**appending.cpp**

```
#include "ProgressBar.h"
#include <unistd.h>

#define ITERATIONS 10

int main()
{
    ProgressBar progress(ITERATIONS, "Looking for odd numbers...");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        // Sleep for 0.5s so that the gif is clear enough
        usleep(500000);

        if (i%2 != 0)
        {
            progress.printNewMessage(
                    "New odd number found: " + std::to_string(i));
        }

        ++progress;
    }
}
```

**Output of appending.cpp**

[image]

Comment: What is the output now? The question didn't show any expectations, and your answer doesn't show any actual results.

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question to show what I meant exactly. The output of this answer gives two options to the user: either print on top of the bar, respecting the previously printed message and moving the bar down; or "update" (i.e. overwrite) the previously printed message. The output will depend on the use. The key is to not print to the screen directly with `std::cout`, but moving the cursor before and after.

Comment: @sehe I just added a couple of snippets of code showing how to use the class and what output should be expected from it, hopefully it's more useful now :)

Comment: Always upvote gifs. It's not what I'd use, but I guess it's good to have without breaking out cUrl